# node.js - Change div color on database notification

Tags: html, node.js, database, postgresql, notify

I'm going to make monitoring system (which is connected to database). Any changes are determinate by trigger (notification) in database.

- When someone will detect, color breached area (represented by div
  in html file) should change on red, and in this div text will show
  "ALARM" or sth.
- If on any area will happen something unexpected, color should be
  yellow, and text "ANOMALY".
- After confirming alarm, color should return to green (I thing, to
  confirm, I use POST, when PHP will send insert into database to release trigger).

**Database events table**

- id -> event id (as AutoIncrement)
- area_id -> id of area
- situation -> whats exactly happened (1 - normal state, 2 - anomaly, 3 - alarm)

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_notifaj
  AFTER INSERT
  ON notifaj
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE fun_notifaj();
```

**Trigger function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_notifaj()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify(
        CAST('notifaj' AS text),
        (
            (NEW.id)::text || '|' ||
            (NEW.area_id)::text || '|' ||
            (NEW.situation)::text 
        ));
    return new;
END;
$BODY$
```

**test.js:**

```
var app       =     require("express")();
var http      =     require('http').Server(app);
var io        =     require("socket.io")(http);
var pg        =     require ('pg');
var status = '';

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/x.html');
});


pg.connect("postgres:x@localhost:5432/notifaje", function(err, client) 
{
    if(err) 
        console.log(err);

    io.on('connection',function(socket)
    {  



console.log("A user is connected");

        socket.on('disconnect', function()
        {
            console.log('user disconnected');

        });

        client.on('notification', function(msg) 
        {

          console.log('St: ' + status)
          if (msg.name === 'notification' && msg.channel === 'notifaj')
          {
              if(status != msg.payload)
              {
              console.log(msg.payload);
              status = msg.payload;

              add_status(status,function(res)
              {
                  io.emit('refresh feed',status);
              }); 
              } 
          }
        });
    });
    client.query("LISTEN notifaj");

});    

    var add_status = function (status,callback) 
    {
      if(status) 
      {
    callback(true);
      }
      else
      {
    callback(false);
    return;
      }

    }


http.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Listening on 3000");
});
```

**x.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Monitoring</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src = "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
          var socket = io();

          socket.on('refresh feed',function(msg){
            $("#show_comments").append(msg + '<br /><br />');

          });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="area1" style="background-color:green;">Area1</div>
    <div id="area2" style="background-color:green;">Area2</div>
    <div id="area3" style="background-color:green;">Area3</div>
    <div id="area4" style="background-color:green;">Area4</div>
    <div id="area5" style="background-color:green;">Area5</div>
    <div id="area6" style="background-color:green;">Area6</div>

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

App is based on tutorial from: https://codeforgeek.com/2015/03/real-time-app-socket-io

Comment: why your socket.io code in database connection?